# Get rotated rectangle points from x, y, width, height and rotation

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, trigonometry

I have a rectangle which is rotated (in this case 45 degrees) and looks like this:

[image: My rectangle]

And I know that X is from the top left corner of the rectangle (if it were unrotated, in this case the point at the top of the picture). Y is also from the top left corner. I have the width and the height and the bounding box. I want to find out what the other points of this rectangle are. The top left (technically the X position in this case), the top right, the bottom right and the bottom left. I was trying to use a transformation matrix but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

How would one find the other points of this rectangle? Technically I am working in JavaScript but any language should be able to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 6):

for anybody else looking for this. Here is a function to do so.

x,y,height and width are as shown in the picture below.
ang is the angle between the x,y point and the Y-Axis.
if you want the one between the x,y point and the X-Axis simply do so:
`ang = 90 - ang` 
before sending it to the function

isDeg is simply whether you are sending the ang in Radians or Degrees.

```js
function getRectFourPoints(x,y, width, height, ang, isDeg = false) {
   
 if(isDeg) ang = ang * (Math.PI / 180)

 const points = {first: {x,y}}
 const sinAng = Math.sin(ang) 
 const cosAng = Math.cos(ang)
 
 let upDiff = sinAng * width
 let sideDiff = cosAng * width
 const sec = {x: x + sideDiff, y: y + upDiff}
 points.sec = sec
 
 upDiff = cosAng * height
 sideDiff = sinAng * height
 points.third = {x: x + sideDiff, y: y - upDiff}
 
 const fourth = {x: sec.x + sideDiff, y: sec.y - upDiff}
 points.fourth = fourth
 return points
}
```

[image: example triangle]

Answer (score 0):

The rotation matrix can help to calculate its current position based on its previous one. If it's rotating clockwise, the 2D rotation matrix is as follows:

[image]

which makes

[image]
[image]

Comment: So is `x'` the original x or is `x` the original x?

Comment: @Johnston Former coordinates (x,y). New coordinates (x',y'). Note that this formula is for rotation about coordinate origin (0,0)

Comment: @MBo is correct, (x', y') is the new coordinate transformed from (x, y). Sorry for the confusion.